# Can I improve performance of a PUT request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am using a json-server where I store my database in JSON objects. At some point, I have to update all the values in one of those objects, which is an array. The problem is that when I apply that function that updates the values, the server shuts down. I know that this is happening because I am interacting with the server in a for loop, and I suppose that this is not the best way to do that communication with the server. Here's the code:

The reducer:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const Inventario = (state = { errMess: null, inventario: []}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   case ActionTypes.EDIT_INGREDIENTE:
      return {...state, inventario: state.inventario.map((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? 
                 action.payload : item)};
   default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Action Creator:

```
export const editIngrediente = (ingrediente) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.EDIT_INGREDIENTE,
    payload: ingrediente
});

export const putIngrediente = (ingredienteId, nombreIngrediente, costo, disponible, conversiones) => (dispatch) => {

    const newIngrediente = {
      id: ingredienteId,
      ingrediente: nombreIngrediente,
      costo: costo,
      disponible: disponible,
      conversiones: conversiones
    };

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'inventario/' + ingredienteId, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(newIngrediente),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            throw error;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {dispatch(editIngrediente(response)); console.log('editado con exito')})
    .catch(error =>  { console.log('put ingrediente', error.message); alert('Your ingredient could not be posted\nError: '+error.message); });
};
```

And finally where I applied the code:

```
function restarIngrediente(ingrediente){
        for (var elem of ingrediente){
          var restar = elem.gramos;
          var enInventario = inventario.filter((inven) => inven.ingrediente === elem.ingrediente)[0];
          var restante = enInventario.disponible - restar;
          putIngrediente(enInventario.id, enInventario.ingrediente, enInventario.costo, restante, enInventario.conversiones);
        }
      }
```

Another doubt that I have is that when I want to update the object, I have to pass to the fetch all the attributes of the object, and not only the one that I actually want to change.

If someone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Try to put inside one fetch all ingredientes. it's help to live your server and reduce network traffic. On server side if you cannot put data bulk, try to parse request to array and push data in loop cycle, but on server side.

Comment: is there a reason you are not using async?

Comment: async not solve the basic problem

Comment: The problem is that I have different recipes, so the "ingredientes" that are passed, changes according to the recipe. So in the first instance, I wouldn't know what "ingredientes" put in the fetch.